# Java instantiate class from string

Tags: java

I have the following,

```
public interface SuperbInterface
public class A implements SuperbInterface
public class B extends A
public class C extends B
```

I want to instantiate `C` but I seems to be getting `B`, what did I do wrong?

```
Class classz = Class.forName("C");
SuperbInterface superb = (SuperbInterface)classz.newInstance();

//Here when I debug it seems to be going to B.doWork() methods instead of C.doWork().
superb.doWork();
```

Comment: have you overriden doWork in `C` ?? please show the relevant code fully

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only thing I can think of is that you haven't overridden **doWork()** in C.

Maybe you have tried ot override but with some spelling mistake in method name or wrong parameters?

Comment: As it turns out there is an obsolete jar in the build path, it so happens in this jar `C` has not yet override `B`'s doWork. duh!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using a newer version of Java add [@Override](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/annotations.html) to the doWork method.  If you have incorrectly overriden the method the compiler will then let you know.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that `C` overrides the `doWork` method? Based on the question as it is posed it is perfectly reasonable/legal to expect that as part of extending `B`, `C` does not provide its own implementation for `doWork` and instead relies on the one provided the superclass `B`.

Answer (score 0):

I see the outcome:

A's do work

whats the things you are expecting ?