# Create Object of an Interface by String

Tags: java, interface, classloader

I have the following interface

```
package test.test;

public interface IMyInterface {
 public String hello();
}
```

and an implementation

```
package test.test.impl;

public class TestImpl implements IMyInterface {
 public String hello() { return "Hello"; }
}
```

So I have only the full String "test.test.impl.TestImpl". How can I load the Class and create a Object from the Implementation?

I will use the current Classloader but I have no idea to create a Object.

```
Class<?> i =  getClass().getClassLoader().loadClass("test.test.impl.TestImpl");
IMyInterface impl = null;
```

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 4):

With [Class.newInstance](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance%28%29). The drawback of this approach is, though, that it suppresses checked exceptions (and introduces new reflection related exceptions) and always no-arg.
Alternatively you can use [Class.getConstructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getConstructor%28java.lang.Class...%29) (then `Constructor.newInstance`), this way you can provide the arguments, but the exception problem is still there.

Comment: What do you mean by "always no-arg"? You can instantiate a new instance with args/parameters like this: Object obj = klass.getConstructor(parameterTypes).newInstance(parameterArr);

Comment: True, I could have written it cleaner. Class.newInstance is no-arg, but Constructor.newInstance is parametrizable.

Answer (score 2):

Use reflection:

```
TestImpl ti  = (TestImpl) Class.forName("test.test.impl.TestImpl").newInstance();
```

Answer (score 2):

[Use](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getConstructor%28java.lang.Class...%29) `impl = (IMyInterface) i.getConstructor().newInstance();`

Answer (score 1):

```
Class<?> clazz = ....
Object o = clazz.newInstance();
// o will be a valid instance of you impl class
```

It will call the default constructor (you must have one!).

Answer (score 0):

```
IMyInterface impl = null;
Class testImpl = Class.forName("test.test.impl.TestImpl");
if(testImpl != null && IMyInterface.class.isAssignableFrom(testImpl.getClass()) {
    impl = testImpl.getConstructor().newInstance();
}
```

Also, check: 1) [Using Java Reflection - java.sun.com](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/ALT/Reflection/)
             2) [Java instantiate class from string - Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178205/java-instantiate-class-from-string)